# Как получить слуайное значение из массива в Си?

Tags: c, массивы, генерация-случайных-данных

Есть массив, например:

```
char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

И нужно из него получить случайное значение и записать его в переменную.

(Зарание извиняюсь, если такой вопрос уже был, я нашел только с примером в С++)

Comment: В общем виде `char с = arr[rand()%(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))];`

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли!